# CrossAxisAlignment.center never working in Column

Tags: android, flutter

CrossAxisAlignment.center never working in Column.

My code:

```
body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Hello word')
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: do you want to center the text vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Please post your complete class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the column with `SizedBox.expand(`

```
SizedBox.expand((
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[ Text('Hello word') ],
),
)
```

Comment: It will center on screen, I just it center horizontal on top of screen.

Comment: If i only use `column`, width of the column is not expanded (just wrap child). Therefore `crossAxisAlignment` look like wrong. I should wrap `column` with a widget parent, maybe `SizedBox`, `Container` and expand width of it.

Comment: `width of the column is not expanded` this is the key. @mducc